# Can I call an exist javascript function into jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

Can I make a jQuery function that can call an existing Javascript function. But, that Javascript function are from different file.

First I have a button that will open modal dialog that contain a form.Before the form popup I want to check the validation first by using a function that already exist.

```
<body>
<input type="button" name="buttonform" id="buttonform" value="Open Modal Form" />
<div id="dialogform"  align = "center">
   DIALOG
<form name="myForm2" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
 Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>   
</body>
```

jQuery function:

```
<script>
$(function openform(){

$("#dialogform").dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    title: "Modal Form",
    width: 700,
    height: 400,
});

$('#buttonform').click(function (){

        $('#functioncheckheader')//function to call from other javascript file
        $('#dialogform').dialog('open');     
});
})
</script>
```

Example of javascript function from different file:

```
function checkheader(){

if($('#company').val() == 'select')
{   alert("Please select the date in header");     }
else if($('#project').val() == 'select')
{   alert("Please select the project in header");       }
else if($('#reqType').val() == 'select')
{   alert("Please select the request type");       }
else if($('#la').val() == "")
{   alert("Please fill up the LA no.");      }
else if($('#workScope').val() == "")
{   alert("Please select the work scope.");     }

}
```

BTW,I am new in jQuery. Thank you !!

Comment: yes, you can do that

Comment: Use `checkheader()` instead of `$('#functioncheckheader')`

Comment: That is possible, as long as `checkheader` is exposed globally.

Comment: as long as you import that file using `<link>` or `<script>` tag.

Comment: I see . Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add the js file to your HTML right after your jQuery

```
<html>
   <head>
       <script src="functionToUse.js"></script>
   </head>
</html>
```

If you wish to use a function from that file in your jQuery code.

```
$('#buttonform').click(function (){
     funcFromFile(); //function to call from other javascript file
     $('#dialogform').dialog('open');      
});
```

Comment: The custom js should be *after* the jquery.js include as the it uses jquery.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that @freedomn-m